# npm install command error

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, web-part, typescript, npm

**Sample:**(PS: You can find what I tested in the GitHub link below)

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-mgtEvents/src/webparts/mgtEvents/MgtEventsWebPart.ts

**Problem:**
Hello,

I would like to add the react-mgtEvents web part to my SharePoint Online site. I installed the node-js version from the below URL:https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.24.1/

After that, I tried to execute the npm install command on the react-mgtEvents folder path. However, I am getting the below errors after it finishes: What are the dependencies that should be installed for this solution to make it run successfully and upload the app to the SharePoint app catalog? Can please someone provide the steps needed?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some dependencies builds on your pc after them downloaded, so, did you see this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372618/npm-cant-find-python-executable-python-you-can-set-the-python-env-variabl

Comment: i have tried all the commands listed in the link above by you and i tried to many node versions including its proper npm:
node: 16.x, 13.x,12.x,10.x

but whenever i use the node 10.x version an error prompt pops-up saying that nmp doesn't support lower node version

When i use the other versions of node the errors in the pictures above pops-up

My main target is to make ' nmp install ' command work in order to continue with my next commands 

I don't know if the problem is form node version or npm version or from the packages

Comment: @Maxim Could you please try to install it on your end and provide the steps needed with the packages installation needed to make sure it is working? I look forward to your response.

Answer (score 1):

So, I checked this solution in my environment and I got the same error. The error occurs due to the fact that some old packages are compiled immediately after downloading. In new versions of NPM, this was abandoned, so an error appears.

In my case this is expected. I have:

```
node -v
v14.16.1

npm list -g --depth=0
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1
+-- gulp@4.0.2
`-- yo@4.1.0
```

Because I build spfx webparts by latest spfx version. So, you can install microsoft 365 cli:

```
npm i @pnp/cli-microsoft365 -g
```

and then upgrade solution to spfx@1.12.1:

```
m365 spfx project upgrade
```

this command show you steps for upgrading spfx solution, after you do them your project will be successfully builds (don't forget to install gulp@4.0.2 in project)

Second solution:

- downgrade to node 10.x
- prepare environment to work with spfx@1.4.1 (or early)
- install old version python2.7 to folder c:\python27
- install node-gyp

Bud this solution you should provide only if you build spfx solutions to on premises farm.

[spfx version compatibility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)
[spfx prepare environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)